How to Customize Links in Firebase Auth Email Templates?
I am currently integrating Firebase Authentication into my web application, utilizing email and password for user authentication. I have encountered a challenge with customizing the links provided in the default email templates for email verification and password reset.
The default template sends a URL that looks like this:

Hello,
Follow this link to verify your email address.
https://PROJECTNAME.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode={oobCode}&apiKey={APIKey}&lang=en
If you didn’t ask to verify this address, you can ignore this email.
Thanks,

While I am satisfied with the template's content, I wish to modify how the link is presented. Specifically, I aim to replace the URL with a simple "Click here" hyperlink or alternatively, to hide the oobCode and apiKey parameters from the user in the displayed link.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this customization within Firebase's email template settings or through additional coding?
